# Desktop software development timeline

Tags: history

What are the most significant events that impacted desktop software development? I'm trying to come up with a good timeline but I know I'm missing a bunch of important events:

1. Introduction of the personal computer (lates 70s?)
2. Release of VisiCalc (1980)
3. WordPerfect 4.2 in 1986
4. Windows 3.1 (1992)
5. Visual Basic
6. Windows 95...

Java, X11, .NET, Delphi, PowerBuilder, QT?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about the history of programming are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276366/4284627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Machines, here;s the [Wikipedia Timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization_Development). Pick your significant event:-)

Also here's a preety detailed [timeline.](http://www.islandnet.com/~kpolsson/comphist/mini.htm)

Comment: That second timeline is a great reference! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Invention of the Mouse

Answer (score 0):

- Mouse
- Graphical User Interface
- Monitor (They didn't always have displays).

Comment: Excellent points! What really started GUIs going though? Would that be considered Apple's first release of the Mac or Lisa machine?

Answer (score 0):

Without the pc there where no desktop applications. It was the first time that ordinary people could but a computer.

Before that, if you where lucky you had a single terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Bushy Tree Diagram](http://www.digibarn.com/stories/desktop-history/bushytree.html) showing the R&D work at [Xerox PARC](http://www.parc.com/) and the profound influence it has had on personal computer technology ever since.  One [Alan Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48710/alan-kay) was a key player in the research that went on there.

Answer (score 0):

Borland's [Turbo Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal): Famous for lightning-fast compile times I'm told.